# Git commit gets permission denied but works with --no-verify

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

When I run, `git commit -m 'Test'` am getting this message:

```
[INFO] Initializing environment for git@github.com:humitos/mirrors-autoflake.git.
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git', 'fetch', 'origin', '--tags')
return code: 128
expected return code: 0
stdout: (none)
stderr:
    git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.

Check the log at /Users/amit/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

But if run, `git commit -m 'Test' --no-verify`, it works fine. Something is wrong with my pre commit hook, any ideas?

Comment: Your `pre-commit` hook tries to run `git fetch origin --tags` and fails authenticating. Can you run the command manually?

Comment: thanks @phd, yes I tried running it manually and it works fine, pulls new branches without any issue.

Comment: My next idea is more complex — the `pre-commit` hook uses `sudo` to run the command under a different user thus loosing access to the SSH key. But without looking into the code of the hook it'd be hard to debug.

Comment: You are right @phd! I fixed some file permissions, although now getting this,

```An error has occurred: InvalidManifestError:
=====> /Users/amit/.cache/pre-commit/repo29erukkj/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml does not exist
Check the log at /Users/amit/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log```

Answer (score 2):

It appears your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file references a git repository using an ssh url, but you don't have an ssh key for github configured

You can safely replace the reference to `repo: git@github.com:humitos/mirrors-autoflake` with `repo: https://github.com/humitos/mirrors-autoflake` (especially because this is a public repository)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by remove below line from ***.gitconfig***

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```